# Databases: User Profiles

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Is it a bad idea to include all user information in one table? Would it be a good idea to have a `users` table and a `user_profiles` table?

*Which method is best and why?*

*Under what circumstances would you employ one/two table(s)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relation between those tables is one-to-one I would have one table. If the relation is one-to-many (one user can have more than one profile) then these obviously should be split.

Another reason to split the tables could be permissions management - it is easier for DBA to restrict permissions to one table and grant to another. I would still have one table with restricted permissions and a public view with limited columns.

I inherited a system where those two tables are split without a good reason for it. It is a pain in the neck to join those tables always. In the end you end up with having a view and asking yourself why the split was made in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a person table and a user table. The users table holds all of the user information (username, password (encrypted), etc). The person table holds names, etc.

Comment: Okay, but why? The OP is asking which method is best, and when to use each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Summer. I don't see any issue in having all of the information in the same table.

The benefit to having it all in one table is that you won't have to do joins, etc when running database queries. Which means your application would run faster.

Comment: Then why would you ever have two?  It seems like that's pretty standard practice...

Comment: In my 3 years as a programmer, I've learned that standard practice does not always equal good ;) However, it may benefit you if you have a ton of user information and you're worried it would get unweildy. What "user" information are you worried about? I agree with Summer's person/user system.

Comment: I didn't read through all of this, but check out #5: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/ (In a database, the process of normalization, as a means of breaking down and isolating data, takes every table to the point where one row represents one thing.) So it think about whether you can break down a user into separate things. I have never come across a situation where I broke it down.